# Powershell dictionary not adding correctly

Tags: powershell

I have an xml file as given below.

```
<Packages>
  <package name="testR0" testversion="1.0.0.0" type="A">
    <package name="testR1" testversion="1.0.0.1" type="A">
    </package>
    <package name="testR2" testversion="1.1.0.0" type="A">
        <package name="testR3" testversion="1.1.1.0" type="B">
          <package name="testR4" testversion="1.1.1.1" type="C">
          </package>
          <package name="testR5" testversion="1.1.1.2" inc="true" type="C">
          </package>
          <package name="testR6" testversion="1.1.1.3" inc="true"  type="C">
          </package>
        </package>
   </package>
  </package>
</Packages>
```

Need to add the testversion and type of two given package name to a dictionary. If I pass `TestR0` and `TestR3` then it should add the testversion and type from `TestR2`, `TestR3` and also `TestR5` and `TestR6` where the `inc=true`. So the resulting dictionary should look like

```
{[1.1.0.0, A],[1.1.1.0, B],[1.1.1.2, C],[1.1.1.3, C]}
```

But even though I'm getting the values the dictionary is not getting populated correctly. It is coming as given below. Only `[1.1.0.0, A]` is coming inside dictionary

```
{[1.1.0.0, A]},[1.1.1.0, B],[1.1.1.2, C],[1.1.1.3, C]
```

My code is given below

```
 function Get-Listver {

PROCESS {
    
    [xml] $versionInfo = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\test\test.xml" 
  
    $firstXML = Select-Xml -Xml $versionInfo -XPath "//*[@name='testR0']"
   
    $secondXML = Select-Xml -Xml $versionInfo -XPath "//*[@name='testR3']"
      
   $packagecollection = Get-AllPackageVersion $secondXML.Node $firstXML.Node 
    return $packagecollection
     }
  }


 function Get-AllPackageVersion {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $secondXML,
    $firstXML
)
process {
  
    $packagecollection = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"[String,String]"
    
    if($secondXML.type -eq 'B'){
        $preReq = $secondXML.ChildNodes | Where-Object {$_.inc -eq "true"}
        if($preReq)
        {

        foreach($pq in $preReq)
        {
            $testver = $pq.testversion
            $testtyp = $pq.type
            $packagecollection.Add("$testver", "$testtyp")
        }
    }
    }
    
    $testver = $secondXML.testversion
    $testtyp = $secondXML.type
    $packagecollection.Add("$testver", "$testtyp")

    if($secondXML.ParentNode.Name -ne $firstXML.ParentNode.Name -and $secondXML.ParentNode.Name -ne $firstXML.Name){
        Get-AllPackageVersion $secondXML.ParentNode $firstXML 
    }

   
    if ($packagecollection.count -gt 1) 
    {
        $packagecollection = $packagecollection.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property key
    }
    return $packagecollection;
  }
 }

  Get-Listver
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If I run the code using your example xml I seem to get the result you're after - i.e. an array of key-value pairs like ```{ [1.1.0.0, A], [1.1.1.0, B], [1.1.1.2, C], [1.1.1.3, C] }```. Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: I have added an image in the question.I'm getting it like that

Comment: I've seen this issue I believe.. I believe it's something like the first record you need to unwrap manually and the remaining powershell unwraps for you. Not finding the info I'm after yet.

Comment: **1st** Use `[void]$packagecollection.Add("$testver", "$testtyp")` because  the `Add` method returns an integer which would become a part of returned collection. **2nd** The (conditional) `… .GetEnumerator() | sort …` causes that returned value is (incostintetly) either ```Dictionary`2``` or  (an array of) ```KeyValuePair`2```.

Comment: Hi JosefZ,
Otherwise how i can sort it by maintaining the Dictionary structure

Comment: @JosefZ No, `Dictionary<TKey,T>.Add()` doesn't return any output (you might be thinking of `ArrayList`)

Comment: @tjdoubts What is the logic behind excluding `testR1` (when it's parent `testR0` is passed in)? Just trying to understand the relationship between the arguments and the desired output

Comment: TestR1 doesn't have any child nodes. TestR2 is the parent node for TestR3.
I want a way to sort the dictionary on the base of keys(version is the key here). As JosefZ said , GetEnumerator is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try the following modification of your script:

```
function Get-AllPackageVersion {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $secondXML,
        $firstXML
    )
    process {
        if($secondXML.type -eq 'B'){
            $preReq = $secondXML.ChildNodes | Where-Object {'inc' -in $_.psobject.Properties.Name -and $_.inc -eq "true"}
            if($preReq) {
                foreach($pq in $preReq) {
                    $testver = $pq.testversion
                    $testtyp = $pq.type
                    $packagecollection.Add("$testver", "$testtyp")
                }
            }
        }
        $testver = $secondXML.testversion
        $testtyp = $secondXML.type
        $packagecollection.Add("$testver", "$testtyp")
    
        if($secondXML.ParentNode.Name -ne $firstXML.ParentNode.Name -and
           $secondXML.ParentNode.Name -ne $firstXML.Name){
            Get-AllPackageVersion $secondXML.ParentNode $firstXML 
        }
    }
}

function Get-Listver {
  PROCESS {
    [xml] $versionInfo = Get-Content -Raw -Path "C:\test\test.xml" 

    $firstXML  = Select-Xml -Xml $versionInfo -XPath "//*[@name='testR0']"
    $secondXML = Select-Xml -Xml $versionInfo -XPath "//*[@name='testR3']"

    $packagecollection = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"[String,String]"
    Get-AllPackageVersion $($secondXML.Node) $($firstXML.Node)
    return $packagecollection
  }
}

Get-Listver
```

**Output** (there is no reason why an object of [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) type should be "*visually*" sorted):

```
$x = .\SO\63401378.ps1; $x; $x.Count, $x.GetType().Name

Key     Value
---     -----
1.1.1.2 C    
1.1.1.3 C    
1.1.1.0 B    
1.1.0.0 A    
4
Dictionary`2
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @JosefZ's comment, you're outputting 4 items from your function but you've got a bit of a mix of types:

[image: Screenshot of Out-GridView showing values from GetListVer]

The issue is that depending on whether you hit this code path or not:

```bsh
if ($packagecollection.count -gt 1) 
{
    $packagecollection = $packagecollection.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property key
}
```

you're returning either a `Dictionary` or an `System.Object[]` array at the end of the function.

In your specific example, the first item in the output (`testR2`) *doesn't* hit the code path so you get a Dictionary with one item in, but `testR3` hits that code path and outputs a `System.Object[]` array with 3 items in it (`testR3`, `testR5` and `testR6`) which gets unrolled and appended to the output.

The solution is to make sure you're returning consistent types regardless of how many items are in the dictionary. One way to do that is to *always* sort the dictionary to coerce it into an array regardless of how many items are in it.

Change the above snippet to remove the `if`:

```bsh
$packagecollection = $packagecollection.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property key
```

and now you get:

[image]

As an aside, your code is a bit confusing to review because you're mixing implicit output from the recursive call to `Get-AllPackageVersion $secondXML.ParentNode $firstXML` with cmdlet output via `return $packagecollection;`, and your implicit output gets generated half way through building `$packagecollection`. It might be easier to read if you move the
`if($secondXML.ParentNode.Name ...` block to the top of the function to make it clearer that this gets written to the output pipeline first.